# Adding a column into dataframe that is based on the number of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hey guys I have the following issue following a code that would help me do the following.

I have this dataframe (is based on a the max column of MSSQL table that functions as an index there, data is already downloaded and passed to a df):

| last_row |
| --- |
| 39021 |

And I have the following Data frame that was created by consuming several CSV's and other sources:

| blank_col | random column1 | random column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | asgshg2342342d | testdata1 |
|  | asert54363546 | testdata2 |

As you can see the first column is blank and need to insert the index based on the first dataframe so the final product with the column inserted should look like this:

| blank_col | random column1 | random column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 39022 | asgshg2342342d | testdata1 |
| 39023 | asert54363546 | testdata2 |

This is the code that I've been trying and gives me an error

```
last_row_counter = df1.last_row.to_list()

n = int(float(input(last_row)))
df2['column_Id'] = n + 1
```

So basically just inserting the last_row + 1 each row on the second dataframe

Any assistance with this will be much appreciate. PD: apologize for my English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

In you case

```
df2['column_Id'] = np.arange(len(df2)) + lastrowfromdf1 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `squeeze` to the the value from a Series if there're only one, and then create a range and add it to the number:

```
df2['blank_col'] = df1['last_row'].squeeze() + np.arange(df2.shape[0])+1
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
   blank_col  random column1 random column2
0      39022  asgshg2342342d      testdata1
1      39023   asert54363546      testdata2
```